# Convert binary values to datetime python

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I have a binary file and it contains the following values "805783a164fad401" which I need to convert them to datetime

[image: description]

I have tried to use unpack struct function to get the double values and convert the float to datetime but no luck

```
def decode(content):
    test_file_path = content[16:24]
    date_float = unpack('<d', test_file_path)[0]
    print date_float
    seconds = (date_float - 25569) * 86400.0
    print datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds)
```

I expect to see the result Wed, 24 April 2019 06:12:01 UTC. This result obtained from Dcode application that converts the hex to datetime
[image]

Comment: Eh.. `"805783a164fad401"` is a string value, not a binary value...?

Comment: no it is hex collected it from the binary file as showed on the first picture

Comment: Thanks, that made it make much more sense ;-)

Comment: What makes you think that the value is a float?  An integer number of nanoseconds seems a lot more likely for a 64-bit time format.

Comment: I managed to fix it using the following code:
test_file_path = content[16:24].encode("hex")
        nt_timestamp = unpack("<Q", unhexlify(test_file_path))[0]
        epoch = datetime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
        nt_datetime = epoch + timedelta(microseconds=nt_timestamp / 10)
        print nt_datetime.strftime("%c")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a floating-point representation, but rather a 64-bit integer.  And then once decoded, it's not an Excel timestamp (days since 1900) which your formula involving 25569 and 86400 seems to assume, but rather a FILETIME (100-nanosecond chunks since 1601):

```
raw =   '\x80\x57\x83\xa1\x64\xfa\xd4\x01'   # Python 2
#raw = b'\x80\x57\x83\xa1\x64\xfa\xd4\x01'   # Python 3

import struct
unpacked, = struct.unpack('<Q', raw)

import datetime
datetime.datetime(1601,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=unpacked/10.)
# Outputs:
# datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 6, 12, 1, 400000)
```

Comment: Related note: if you're using a binary dump from C++ from a `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` `time_point` and need to interpret it in Python, the code is the same, except the offset is from 1970.  Thanks for this post, it helped me out.